# Unable to open open jupyter notebooks after adding virtual environment to conda. Why?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter-irkernel

I have set a virtual environment called "qiskit_env" in conda, but I was unable to use it jupyter notebook, so I found [this](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/) website to help me set it all up. However, after running the following commands in order:

```
pip install --user ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=qiskit_env
```

I am no longer unable to open any jupyter notebook, and get a message like this on the conda prompt:

```
[I 16:33:44.203 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[E 16:33:44.850 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python3', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1701, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 3178, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 59, in get
        get_custom_frontend_exporters=get_custom_frontend_exporters
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 462, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
        return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\templates\notebook.html", line 120, in block "header"
        {% for exporter in get_custom_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebook\handlers.py", line 24, in get_custom_frontend_exporters
        exporter = get_exporter(name)()
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 958, in __new__
        inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 986, in setup_instance
        super(HasTraits, self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 977, in setup_instance
        value.instance_init(self)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1691, in instance_init
        self._resolve_classes()
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1696, in _resolve_classes
        self.klass = self._resolve_string(self.klass)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1507, in _resolve_string
        return import_item(string)
      File "C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 34, in import_item
        module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from . import postprocessors
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\postprocessors\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .serve import ServePostProcessor
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\postprocessors\serve.py", line 19, in <module>
        class ProxyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
      File "C:\Users\duart\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\postprocessors\serve.py", line 21, in ProxyHandler
        @web.asynchronous
    AttributeError: module 'tornado.web' has no attribute 'asynchronous'
[E 16:33:44.858 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|37d584c5|beb93776ffb29402f03c78a6a3b34c82|1583233584; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1583330621|23:username-localhost-8889|44:ZGE4YTNjODEzNTFiNDg5M2FkZGE1ZGFkY2MxZGM5YTE=|b83ea2d98b45e8584d417bc787e7bc80efb124fb5df074e93c7c87b64c60930a\"; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1583339616|23:username-localhost-8888|44:YWM2MjYxZmE1NDFjNDA3MzhlN2IyNTZlNzJmZjdmMWM=|9b6fd50722a6f64e923e47938c495dfbd7e8dea94f16bd9d7bd996ad3cc317e1\""
    }
[E 16:33:44.861 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1) 534.90ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

Also, while installing the ipykernel I got the following error:

```
WARNING: The scripts jupyter-migrate.exe, jupyter-troubleshoot.exe and jupyter.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel.exe, jupyter-kernelspec.exe and jupyter-run.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script pygmentize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts iptest.exe, iptest3.exe, ipython.exe and ipython3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\duart\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: when you ran `pip install --user ipykernel` was that in your virtual environment?

Comment: yes, I had my virtual environment activated

Comment: when I've hit issues like this in the past, it's ended up being simplest to simply rebuild my Python environment, in particular Jupyter. And then try the venv creation and adding a kernel again, see if it is replicable.

Comment: Funny enough everyrhing went back to nirmal when I made use if the anaconda navigator and installed the Jupiter notebook on my virtual environment.  Everything runs smoothly now

Comment: Good to hear - you may want to put that in as an answer here if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I got it all settled. Unfortunately I have no idea why, but I went to the anaconda navigator, with my virtual environment all set up, and installed Jupyter notebook and Jupyter lab and everything runs smoothly now.